# How does Windows 10 S determine which executable to allow to run?

Tags: winapi, kernel, windows-10

I'm curious how does Windows 10 S kernel implementation of [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) know which process to run and which one to block?

For instance, if we take `Notepad.exe`:

[image]

It has no issues allowing it to run. And it is not even signed:

[image]

But the `regedit.exe` right below it, triggers this:

[image]

I'm curious, how do they differentiate between them?

**EDIT:** *Forgot to mention. If you want to try it for yourself, [Media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) now allows to create a Windows 10 S iso that runs fine in a VM.*

Comment: if this build (S) not allow run debuggers - very hard research this

Comment: [WinDg Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86) *is* a Windows Store app (although it probably cannot run on Windows 10 S).

Comment: @IInspectable: You're correct. It downloads & starts up but then I'm getting `"This application is not supported on this OS version."`

Comment: So this is completely different from regedit.exe, then. After all, it is the executable, that terminates itself, rather than the OS doing so. Running this under a compatibility layer might change things. Or patching the executable image itself (unless it is digitally signed).

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, in that case WinDbg refuses to run itself. As for your patching idea, then no. Anything downloaded from the Store is digitally signed and authenticated so if an executable is patched it won't start.

Comment: You know, a similar behavior exists in Win10 Pro if you choose Settings -> Apps -> Installing Apps and pick "Allow apps from the Store only." If you download anything from the internet and try to run it, it will show a similar window.

Comment: Downloaded files have a "Zone.Identifier" alternate data stream, which gets checked by `ShellExecuteEx`. Are you running this directly via `CreateProcess` or via `ShellExecuteEx` / Explorer?

Comment: @eryksun: `regedit.exe` doesn't have a "mark of the web" zone identifier. It came with Windows in the `system32` folder.

Comment: @eryksun: Oh, no, the last comment is just a similar behavior in Win10 Pro. (Which is probably just a registry setting.) In Win10 S it's implemented on a "deeper level". As for your other point then, no, `cmd.exe` also evokes a similar message and it doesn't have to run elevated.

Comment: Which actually brings an interesting question, "why do they ship it with regedit.exe and cmd.exe, if no one can run them?"

Comment: may be exist some options to enable it ? are custom (say your) programs can run here ?

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, that's the true question .... My application that I can run on 10S is downloaded from a Windows Store. It is a converted Win32 app that comes in a UWP package. If you ask for my guess, I'd say that there's some new registry key or a hidden disk partition that contains signatures on everything that can run. Kinda like whitelisting. But it's only a guess, or how I would do it.

Comment: native (win32) apps (not downloaded from store) can not run here at all ? this os like windows phone but not desktop version ?

Comment: @RbMm: Idk about the phone but Win10S has all prerequisites to run native Win32 apps. (Notepad that can run just fine, or my Store app are native apps.) The only limitation is the artificial one in the process loader.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Windows RT. The early versions could be "hacked" by flipping a bit in kernel memory with a remote debugger to change the signature policy so 3rd-party desktop apps could run.

Comment: Didn't get a chance to answer this before it was put on hold. The answer is on the first page in Google; running user-mode debuggers has nothing to do with is since all the interesting stuff happens in kernel-mode anyway, and there's a very good reason to keep `regedit` etc. I'd suggest starting with Googling something like "how to develop a program for windows 10 s".

Comment: *"why do they ship it with regedit.exe and cmd.exe, if no one can run them?"* - There is more you can do with executable images, than running them. You can search for them, load them into memory as data, or extract resources from them. Maybe an important application (or a first-party module) relies on the existence of regedit.exe to function properly, even if it never tries to launch it, or gracefully handles failure to launch. Speculation, sure, but the answer to this *"interesting"* question is possibly very boring.